# JSON, last line not show properly

Tags: json

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2>

<p>
Name: <span id="jname"></span><br />  
Age: <span id="jage"></span><br /> 
Address: <span id="jstreet"></span><br /> 
Phone: <span id="jphone"></span><br /> 
Memo: <span id="jmemo"></span><br />
</p>  

<script type="text/javascript">
var JSONObject = {
  "name":"John Johnson",
  "street":"Oslo West 16", 
  "age":33,
  "phone":"555 1234567",
  "memo":"hello world !"};
document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=JSONObject.name  
document.getElementById("jage").innerHTML=JSONObject.age  
document.getElementById("jstreet").innerHTML=JSONObject.street  
document.getElementById("jphone").innerHTML=JSONObject.phone  
document.getElementById("jmemo").innerHTML=JSONOject.memo
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result i got is this:

```
JSON Object Creation in Javascript

Name: John Johnson
Age: 33
Address: Oslo West 16
Phone: 555 1234567
Memo:
```

Why after "Memo", there is no "Hello World" as I expected?
Thank you!

Comment: Missing semicolon in the last line? What does your debugger say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("jmemo").innerHTML=JSONOject.memo
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("jmemo").innerHTML=JSONObject.memo
```